# mpandroidchart LineData cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayLIst<java.lang.String>

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

```
package com.example.a401st_35.weather2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LineChart lineChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lineChart = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<Entry> val  = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    val.add(new Entry(100.0f,0));
    val.add(new Entry(100.0f,1));
    val.add(new Entry(100.0f,2));
    val.add(new Entry(100.0f,3));

    LineDataSet setComp1 = new LineDataSet(val,"Company 1");
    setComp1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(setComp1);

    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    xVals.add("1.Q");
    xVals.add("2.Q");
    xVals.add("3.Q");
    xVals.add("4.Q");

    **LineData data = new LineData(xVals,dataSets);**


    lineChart.setData(data);
    lineChart.invalidate();
}
}
```

I've tried other Mpandroid LineCharts but always comes up with the same errors like this one.

LineData(com.github.mikephill.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet...) in LineData cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayLIst, java.util.ArrayList)

```
Error:(53, 25) error: constructor LineData in class LineData cannot be 
applied to given types;
required: ILineDataSet[]
found: ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<LineDataSet>
reason: varargs mismatch; ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to 
ILineDataSet
```

Specifically, 
    [LineData data = new LineData(xVals,dataSets); ] this line is the problem.

Already set build.gradle and also imported jar file. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your library version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give multiple line datasets use following example and also use version 3.0.3 of mpcharts

```
 ArrayList<Entry> lineEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 6));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 9));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 4));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 8));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 12));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 10));

    LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Line1");
    lineDataSet1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet1.setColors(getColor("defaultGreen"));
    lineDataSet1.setLineWidth(3);
    lineDataSet1.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet1.setCircleColor(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    lineDataSet1.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet1.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet1.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet1.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet1.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);
    lineDataSet1.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));
    lineDataSet1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

    ArrayList<Entry> lineEntries2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(0, 8));
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(1, 11));
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(2, 6));
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(3, 10));
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(4, 14));
    lineEntries2.add(new Entry(5, 12));

    LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(lineEntries2, "Line2");
    lineDataSet2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet2.setColors(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(3);
    lineDataSet2.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet2.setCircleColor(getColor("defaultGreen"));
    lineDataSet2.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet2.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet2.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet2.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet2.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);
    lineDataSet2.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));
    lineDataSet2.enableDashedLine(8,16,4);
    lineDataSet2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(lineDataSet1);
    dataSets.add(lineDataSet2);

    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);

    lineChart.setData(data);
    lineChart.animateY(1000);
    lineChart.getDescription().setText("Line Comparison Chart");

    Legend legend = lineChart.getLegend();
    legend.setStackSpace(5);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    // xAxis customization
    XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);

    YAxis leftAxis = lineChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    YAxis rightAxis = lineChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

To give one line dataset use following example:

```
lineEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(0, 10));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(1, 11));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(2, 12));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(3, 14));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(4, 18));
    lineEntries.add(new Entry(5, 31));

    lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "Line");
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineDataSet.setLineWidth(3);
    lineDataSet.setColor(getColor("defaultBlue"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleColor(getColor("defaultOrange"));
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(6);
    lineDataSet.setCircleHoleRadius(3);
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(defaultValueTextSize);
    lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(getColor("primaryDark"));

    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    lineChart.animateY(1000);
    lineChart.setData(lineData);
```

For Custom xAxis values please refer following;

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));



 private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues()
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "JAN");
    labels.add( "FEB");
    labels.add( "MAR");
    labels.add( "APR");
    labels.add( "MAY");
    labels.add( "JUN");
    return labels;
}
```

Comment: So what about `xVals` ?

Comment: new BarEntry(x,y) this is how you give x and y values for custom values you have to create indexvalueformatter. I edited the answer so do follow my instructions it will help you out. Happy coding mate :)